# How to restrict implicit string conversion in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have below content in my NodeJs file . Where i want use the values of cc to be used in HTML page. Variable `cont` will be holding HTML content.

```
var cc=[{"keyword":"a","message":"y"}];    
var cont= '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="reportCtrl"> <table><tr ng-repeat="x in names"><td>{{ x.keyword }}</td><td>{{ x.message }}</td></tr></table></div><script>var app = angular.module("myApp", []);app.controller("reportCtrl", function($scope) {$scope.names= '+  cc  +' ;});</script></body></html>';
```

and writing HTML file

```
fs.writeFile('myPage.html', cont, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('Saved!');
        });
```

When i open HTML page i could find that the value of cc is `[Object Object][Object Object](Implicitly converted as string)`.

Kindly suggest a way to assign cc to `$scope.names`

Comment: cc is array, try cc[0].keyword or cc[0].message

Comment: yes cc is array, Can you elaborate what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **JSON.stringify(cc[0], null, 2)**  Read more on JSON https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```
var cc=[{"keyword":"a","message":"y"}];    
var cont= '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="reportCtrl"> <table><tr ng-repeat="x in names"><td>{{ x.keyword }}</td><td>{{ x.message }}</td></tr></table></div><script>var app = angular.module("myApp", []);app.controller("reportCtrl", function($scope) {$scope.names= '+  JSON.stringify(cc[0], null, 2) +' ;});</script></body></html>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much . This helped, i used JSON.stringify(cc, null, 2) since i need all array elements

Comment: Glad it helped.:)

Answer (score 2):

`cc` is an Array so if you do

```
console.log(cc.keyword);
```

it would be undefined becaust it is an array with an object inside not an object itself but if you check for the first array element like this

```
console.log(cc[0]);
```

you will get the object in the first array element.

```
{keyword: "a", message: "y"}
```

now you can do

```
console.log(cc[0].keyword);
```

and the result will be

```
"a"
```

in your case you need too loop trough each array element like this

```
var cc=[{"keyword":"a","message":"y"}];   
var outputString = '';

cc.map(function(item){ 
   outputString += item.keyword + item.message; 
});
```

now use `outputString` as variable but you need to format it to your needs inside the loop of course

Comment: NO, The expectation is to provide the array as input to ng-repeat in HTML page and not about printing to console, check cont variable defined above.

Comment: i used console logs to show you the way to use your array not how your code has to be

Answer (score 0):

test.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

var cc=JSON.stringify([{"keyword":"a","message":"y"}]);
var cont= '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="reportCtrl"> <table><tr ng-repeat="x in names"><td>{{ x.keyword }}</td><td>{{ x.message }}</td></tr></table></div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script><script>var app = angular.module("myApp", []);app.controller("reportCtrl", function($scope) {$scope.names= '+  cc  +' ;});</script></body></html>';

fs.writeFile('myPage.html', cont, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
});
```

output: myPage.html (source)
`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="reportCtrl"> <table><tr ng-repeat="x in names"><td>{{ x.keyword }}</td><td>{{ x.message }}</td></tr></table></div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script><script>var app = angular.module("myApp", []);app.controller("reportCtrl", function($scope) {$scope.names= [{"keyword":"a","message":"y"}] ;});</script></body></html>`

It seems that you did not import angular.js script.

Comment: No, it will not.

Comment: Tried ,  i could see $scope.names is assigned to undefined

Comment: @Krishnakanthjuluru see the updated answer, you needed to import the angular.js file in the scripts.

Comment: i just removed import statement for better visibility. I have the script tag to import in my actual version.

Answer (score 0):

Using   `JSON.stringify(cc, null, 2)`  helped me in sorting this issue.